# if my dataset is standardized but have outliers should I remove them and re-standardize?

Tags: machine-learning, regularization, outliers, standardization

I have a data set named Geographical Original of Music Data Set from the UCI repository. The data is given standardized but I think it has outliers and I do not know the best way to handle them.

- Remove and re-standardize
- Find the best model that support outliers.
- Another one?

Comment: What constitutes an outlier and how to treat it depends entirely on the method of analysis.  What, exactly, do you plan to do with these data?  How do you characterize outliers?  What is the purpose of your analysis?

Comment: @whuber the purpose of the analysis is to predict the geographical origin of a  song based on 68 features.  The output is a two-component vector that contains the country's latitude and longitude. By 'outliers characterization' you mean whether I perform median imputation, cropping or another technique like this? If so, I don't anything like that. I view the problem as a classification problem, due to it has 33 different countries that I can encode.

Comment: What you might mean by "outlier" remains unclear; it's not even evident that you need to do something special with them, whatever they might be.